# Conditional sums based on the columns are duplicated (by row) in R

Tags: r, dplyr

Working on a bit of a tricky problem. My data set is as follows:

```
df <- data.frame("WS_bTIV" = c(5,0,10),"WS_cTIV" = c(0,5,10),"EQ_bTIV"=c(5,10,10),"EQ_cTIV"=c(10,5,10))

> df
  WS_bTIV WS_cTIV EQ_bTIV EQ_cTIV
1       5       0       5      10
2       0       5      10       5
3      10      10      10      10
```

I am trying to create a total column which will total up the columns that end with "bTIV" regardless with what they begin with. However, the data is duplicated across some columns. For instance, if you look at row 1:

Both the WS_bTIV and the EQ_bTIV column have a value of 5. However, summing these give us 10. However, I know from the data that the actual true total is actually 5 and the value 5 has been duplicated over these columns. So the total in this case should actually just be 5.

Sometimes however, (e.g. in row 2) the value can be 0 and you can just sum up as normal.

The output should be as follows:

```
  WS_bTIV WS_cTIV EQ_bTIV EQ_cTIV Tot_bTIV Tot_cTIV
1       5       0       5      10        5       10
2       0       5      10       5       10        5
3      10      10      10      10       10       10
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are these the only columns in your dataframe or you have many more columns that end with "bTIV"?

Comment: About 20 in total

Comment: And the rationale is: if the values in the variables that end with the same pattern (e.g. "bTIV") are all different, sum them all as normal; otherwise, if there are duplicates, remove them to obtain unique values and sum them up. Is this correct?

Comment: How do you determine whether WS_bTIV and EQ_bTIV should be added or not?

Comment: Yes pretty much. The way I tried was to count the number of duplicates (i.e. count the number of columns with value >0 in each column which ends in the bTIV by row) then divide through by that number

Comment: @MartinGal They will always be identical or one of them will be 0. If they are identical then remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a combination of Daniel O's and det's answers, using `dplyr`:

```r
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Tot_bTIV = sum(unique(c(WS_bTIV, EQ_bTIV))) ,
         Tot_cTIV = sum(unique(c(WS_cTIV, EQ_cTIV))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the sum of unique `bTIV` & `cTIV` values by row

```
df$Tot_bTIV <- apply(df[grepl("bTIV$",colnames(df))], 1, function(x) sum(unique(x)))
df$Tot_cTIV <- apply(df[grepl("cTIV$",colnames(df))], 1, function(x) sum(unique(x)))


> df
  WS_bTIV WS_cTIV EQ_bTIV EQ_cTIV Tot_bTIV Tot_cTIV
1       5       0       5      10        5       10
2       0       5      10       5       10        5
3      10      10      10      10       10       10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(row_id = seq_len(n())) %>%
  pivot_longer(
    -row_id,
    names_to = c(".value", "group"),
    names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)"
  ) %>%
  group_by(row_id, group) %>%
  mutate(Tot = if_else(WS == EQ, WS, WS + EQ)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = group,
    names_sep = "_",
    values_from = c(WS, EQ, Tot)
  ) %>%
  select(-row_id)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  WS_bTIV WS_cTIV EQ_bTIV EQ_cTIV Tot_bTIV Tot_cTIV
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1       5       0       5      10        5       10
2       0       5      10       5       10        5
3      10      10      10      10       10       10
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `c_across` from `dplyr_1.0.0`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     rowwise %>% 
     mutate(Tot_bTIV = sum(unique(c_across(ends_with('bTIV')))), 
            Tot_cTIV = sum(unique(c_across(ends_with('cTIV')))))
# A tibble: 3 x 6
# Rowwise: 
#  WS_bTIV WS_cTIV EQ_bTIV EQ_cTIV Tot_bTIV Tot_cTIV
#    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1       5       0       5      10        5       10
#2       0       5      10       5       10        5
#3      10      10      10      10       10       10
```